# How to compile C source from Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-construction

i have simple C source file created and compiled nicely on GNU gcc/cc. However when I wanted to compile in Visual Studio on Windows it gives me lots of errors. Is there any particular settings to set for VS compiler in order to compile nicely C source code.thanks

C source (standard style ?)

```
   #include <..>

   //function prototype

   int main(){
     // my code here
   }
   /* all my other functions below this */
```

Just found out I can use cl.exe . would try this first.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio C++ or Visual Studio C#?

Comment: 1. need to see your code 2. need to see the errors

Comment: If you are compiling a standard C89 source (without gcc or POSIX extensions) VC++ shouldn't have any problem. Still, to get any meaningful answer you should post the code and the error messages.

Comment: My understanding is that Microsoft C supports C89 or some older version like that. It will barf on lots of proper C90 C.

Comment: False; Microsoft Visual C is fine with ANSI C90.  It doesn't support a lot of C99, on the other hand, although the latest version is much better in that regard.

Comment: thanks. my program is very simple and i do believe it conform to ANSI C90. I will try VS2010 cl.exe and see how it goes. will post updates.

Comment: hi Elliot Frish i am using VS2010 C++

Comment: Stick to GCC but add the -Wall flag to enable almost all warnings, it is also worth looking for a version of lint and running that on your code.

Comment: Just a note: VS2013 fixed a lot of C compiling errors that previously made C development in Visual Studio a royal pain in the...

Comment: thanks to all. fixed it by moving all declarations to the correct place.